# Strapi - Content Type Definition is invalid for api::article.article

Tags: node.js, sqlite, migration, strapi

I am migrating my Strapi app from V3 to V4. I am using the guide [here](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-migrate-from-strapi-v3-to-v4-walkthrough), but after following all steps so far I am running into the error below:

[image: lifecycle errors]

I am stuck at the part of the article where I need to switch my node version and clean re-install all dependencies. But when I run yarn develop it does not work:

[image: blog post section]

---

##### System information

- Strapi Version: 4.2.3
- Operating System: Windows
- Database: sqlite
- Node Version: 16.20.2
- NPM Version: 8.19.4
- Yarn Version: 1.22.21

Comment: post the error as text. not url image

Answer (score 0):

Within the folder src/api/articles/content-types/articles/, there was a file named lifecycle.js, removing this file resolved the issue.